# groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method in groovy script

Tags: groovy

Can some one please help me with the following code. It is causing "groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.setNodeValue() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [//ns:tem:intA, 50] error at line: 14" error.

```
def getaddresponse=context.expand('${Add SOAP Request#response}')

import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder

def addresponseholder= new XmlHolder(getaddresponse) 
addresponseholder.namespaces["ns"]="http://tempuri.org/"

def addresponsenodevalue=                  
    addresponseholder.getNodeValue("//ns:AddResult")

def deleterequest=context.expand('${Delete SOAP Request#request}')
def deleteholder =new XmlHolder (deleterequest)

deleteholder.namespaces["ns"]="http://tempuri.org/"
deleterequest.setNodeValue("//ns:tem:intA",addresponsenodevalue)

def updatedxml=deleterequest.getXml()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that [context.expand(String content)](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/model/propertyexpansion/PropertyExpansionContext.html#expand(java.lang.String)) returns a `String`, which by default does not have the method [setNodeValue(String xpath, Object value)](https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/support/XmlHolder.html#setNodeValue(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)).

Try calling `setNodeValue()` on your `deleteholder` instead:

```
deleteholder.setNodeValue("//ns:tem:intA",addresponsenodevalue)
def updatedxml=deleteholder.getXml()
```

Comment: hey I'm having the same issue with the following script. Can you please help?https://gist.githubusercontent.com/naissa12/fe3909393aa29da3f60c9ce8c81b7b1c/raw/1c136393208b70840e7bf33d308ada8cd081af92/GroovyScript